# Inverse image of compact is compact will map be closed

Tags: general-topology

f onto continuous map such that inverse image of each compact set is compact. Will f be a closed map?

Comment: For future reference, it benefits your Readers to give more context when asking a Question.  For example, what motivated you to ask?  When approaches did you consider/try before posting?  Context doesn't need to be an elaborate discussion, just enough to outline how you think about the problem and its difficulty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, let $X$ be a finite set with more than one element.

Define $X_{\text{trivial}}=X$ equipped with trivial (indiscrete) topology,

and define $X_{\text{discrete}}=X$ equipped with discrete topology.

Define $f:X_{\text{discrete}} \to X_{\text{trivial}}$ as $f(x)=x$.

Clearly, $f$ is onto. Also, any function defined on a discrete space is continuous, hence $f$ is continuous.

Finally, observe that any subspace of both $X_{\text{discrete}}$ and $X_{\text{trivial}}$ is compact, and therefore the inverse image of each compact set is compact.

However, there is a subset $A$ of $X$ with $\emptyset \neq A \neq X$. Observe that $A$ is closed in $X_{\text{discrete}}$ but not in $X_{\text{trivial}}$, so $f$ is not closed.